# Why justify isn't used commonly in web pages?

Tags: html, css

Recently, I found that justifying text inside web pages is considered as a bad practice. In almost all popular web sites including Wikipedia, the developers don't justify the texts on those sites. But justified text is visually more appealing and it looks really good not only in prints but also in screens. I am not getting the exact reason behind omitting text justification by the web UI designers.

I found in some other places that there might be an issue regarding rendering fonts in browser. But I found CSS property `text-align: justify;` is readily available and it renders the text correctly in the browser in justified format.

So what might be the cause behind this? Or, is it a convention followed by web developers from a long time?

Comment: I would suggest [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com) for this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about about [user interface design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) and not programming.

Comment: Mainly, it's harder to read: in smaller columns, without automatic hyphenation, it can cause too big gaps between the words. Usually, if you see justified text, there is hyphenation, which makes that less of a problem.

Comment: This post is now too old to be migrated.

Answer (score 2):

Justifying text especially on the web means spreading out the words on the line to span the whole column. The result is big gaps between the words. Sometimes these gaps line up and form what’s called rivers within the text block. The point of text is to be read, so don’t sacrifice that just to have some crisp lines along the edges.always stick to the basic and  good practices.

Comment: Rivers can also occur in non-justified text.

Comment: @Xufox I agree with you , but still , i think that the tech of the web isn't ready yet for justification